# Is there an adverb for "simplified"?

Tags: adverbs, syntactic-analysis

This is what I'm trying to express

> [Foo] can be *simplifiedly* characterised as [bar].

However I am unable to find references for such as word as *simplifiedly*. What I want to say is that the following characterisation as [bar] is to be understood as being simplified for the sake of explaining [Foo] in the first place.

How would you phrase it? I would prefer if the structure of the sentence would remain unchanged. But if there is no such word maybe this can be restructured without being too verbose.

---

Edit: It's not a question of rhythm or aesthetics, it's a question of meaning. I'm not trying to say that the characterisation I'm making is simple to derive, I'm trying to say that I'm making a characterisation that is simplifying the matter of [Foo], which is in fact a bit more general/complicated than its representation as [bar] might suggest.

For me "*simply*" has the taste of what I'm not trying to say (according to the above paragraph). Regarding the suggested "*more simply*", I have no gut feeling and will have to trust you as experts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gnawme suggests *simply*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51005), which is good, but means "in a simple manner", not "in a simplified (=made more simple than it was previously) manner". For that, I'd suggest *more simply*.

> [Foo] can be more simply characterised as [bar].

*Edit, in response to the edit to the question:*

1. I'm no expert.
2. Perhaps *can as an oversimplification be characterised* or *can in an oversimplification be characterised*.

Comment: Actually, MW defines _simply_ as "in a straightforward manner," but I do like your suggestion. For the purpose of the OP's exposition, [foo] is being presented as a more simple conception of [bar].

Comment: Would you kindly check the edit in my original question?

Comment: I'll drop the "over": "*as a simplification*" seems about right (even though it's not as catchy as my home-made word). Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Simply would be the most immediate adverb. Others such as: Commonly, reductively, easily, naturally, straightforwardly, conveniently, efficiently, fluently, quickly, might also work. By the sound of it, you are looking for the adverb *simply*; however, for the sake of rhythm and aesthetics, you seem to be looking for a word with more syllables. Instead, this simple change seems to do the trick:

[Foo] can be *more simply* characterised as [bar].

Comment: Would you kindly check the edit in my original question?

Comment: To simplify something can have either of the meanings make simpler or make simple (though the second sense always implies [in the strict mathematical sense] the first). DAWR's paraphrase is fine for the first sense; the second sense needs something like: 'Put simply: [Foo] can be characterised as [bar].' or 'In simple terms, [Foo] can be characterised as [bar].'

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the word you're looking for is [*simplistically*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/simplistically), if you're trying to suggest intentional oversimplification.

Comment: That has a bitter after-taste of "*oversimplified*" which I'd like to avoid :)

Comment: @bitmask: Sure thing, it'd be great to see an actual example of the kind of content you're dealing with.

Comment: I didn't want to obfuscate the matter with computer science gobbledygook, but if you ask for it: "*[Foo]*" expands to "*The input model of non-distributed applications*" and "*[bar]*" expands to "*a Halting Turing Machine*". Happy? :)

Comment: @bitmask, thanks, the context does help I think. (And I have a BE (Comp) so that's not entirely Greek to me.)

Comment: @bitmask I would most definitely use *effectively* in this circumstance.

Comment: I agree, "simplistically" is perfect for this situation.

Answer (score 3):

While *simply* would be correct, it may be slightly misleading, because it can also mean something like "just", as in *that is simply not correct*. *Simplifiedly* sounds a bit unwieldy. You could simply say it like this:

> The policy of the Roman Senate towards Carthage between the wars can be simplified as containment. In so doing, historians amplify the contrast with later policies.

Answer (score 2):

[I modified my answer after seeing your edit.]

To capture what you're after in your exposition, you need to *modify* "simplified:"

> [Foo] can be *conceptually* simplified as [bar].

Answer (score 2):

For your example, I usually use the word *effectively*

> [Foo] can be effectively characterised as [bar].

I don't think I'd generalize *effectively* as the adverb form of *simplified*, but I believe it works well in this case.

Comment: +1.  Given the specific example @bitmask gave in the comments, this is definitely how I'd say it.

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty seems to be arising from at least two things here.

1. Excessive modification from the root.

   > simple -> simplify -> simplified -> ... [a derivation to far from the root for comfort (of the ordinary reader)]<
2. The choice of the word *simple* itself, which is insufficient to express your intention in the given context.

---

[Edit-1 per OP's edit seen just now]

> ... can, in simple terms, be characterised as ...

would be a more direct way to express it according to OP's intentions.

Comment: and to think all this is about simplification of something! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd opt for a word like *essentially* or *roughly*, which imply that the answer is inexact but effective.

Comment: Seems to me the question was seeking greater impact by greater - more punctilious - exactness. It's as if the adverb coinage choice was meant to transcend simplified's merely basic, rough, or effective meanings. Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The essence of [foo] is [bar].
[Foo] is essentially [bar].
[Foo] can be distilled as [bar].
In simplified terms [foo] is [bar].
[Foo] is really [bar].

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your stated aim, it seems that juxtaposition of implied opposites, in the abstract so to speak--as in overstatement by understatement (or, depending on point of few, its converse)--might give the sentence your intended prosaic impact:

> [Foo] can be simplifiedly characterised as [bar].

*

> Simplistically speaking, [Foo] can (or could) be characterised as [bar].

*

The unspoken implication that way is that *simply* (or other mere undersimplifiedifications)  is not quite enough, not quite sufficiently adroit, simplification.